# Error importing PDF image to convert to text

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract, python-imageio

I have a PDF image for transfer to image format so I am trying to read the PDF image and store the data in the text file.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('1.pdf')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
with open('1.txt', mode='w') as file:
    file.write(text)
```

When I run this I get the error `can't set attribute`

Comment: Does it give you a line number where this error comes from?

Comment: \AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py in _open(self)
     63         flags = i8(s[17])
     64 
---> 65         self.size = i16(s[12:]), i16(s[14:])